# XAMPP issue with Mac OS Catalina

Tags: mysql, apache, xampp, macos-catalina

I have been using XAMMP on my mac, it was working fine before OS update to Catalina.

I am not able to start MySQL and Apache. I read the blog that Apache and Php are built-in with Mac OS Catalina, this might be the issue, I have been using 64-bit XAMMP

Comment: Tell more about your problem. Why doesn't it start? Did you get an error message? Whats in the logs of the apache?

Answer (score 13):

The manager-osx is not working, but you can start it through the terminal. Go to /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles and type:
sudo ./xampp start

Answer (score 6):

I had to first stop MACOS web server and then start Apache and MySql. The sequence I used was:

```
sudo apachectl stop
cd /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles
sudo ./xampp startapache
sudo ./xampp startmysql
```

Works fine.

Comment: Thanks for this. This solution worked but is there any better solution like we were using manager-osx/xampp to control server services.

Answer (score 1):

Download the latest version of XAMMP [here](https://www.apachefriends.org/es/download.html), it works with Mac OS Catalina.

Please note the installer version

- For Package Installer > https://www.apachefriends.org/xampp-files/7.4.1/xampp-osx-7.4.1-1-installer.dmg
- For Virtual Machine > https://www.apachefriends.org/xampp-files/7.4.1/xampp-osx-7.4.1-1-vm.dmg

In another case use the solution already described, through the terminal:

`sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/xampp start`

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that your XAMPP is located under the Application folder.
Please run the below command on your terminal to start the Apache, MySQL, and ProFTPD

sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/xampp start

Comment: it works for me, but I want it that I can also start it directly in the XAMPP control panel --> like in the past. Any solutions here?

Comment: @MarioKurzweil I will Update you once I get the solution

Answer (score 0):

open xampp-manager >> networks.

edit both ports and uncheck:
1. require local
2. over SSH

save and restart services and it should work now